# image for specific class does not work when used on body?

Tags: html, css

i have this for a custom class in my css:

```
.login-img-body{

  background-image: url('../img/loginWallpaper.jpg') no-repeat center center     fixed; 

  -webkit-background-size: cover;

  -moz-background-size: cover;

  -o-background-size: cover;

  background-size: cover;

}
```

if I use this class on a regular div the image is applied, but if I use the class on a body the image does not appear. the body doesn't have any other classes.

Comment: It probably has other, more specific styles, though. Use your browser's developer tools to check.

Comment: `CSS` rules apply based on specificty. There are other rules overriding the ones defined in the declaration above which take precedence. Search for `CSS` specificty to understand what's going on. And follow @lonesomeday's advice.

Comment: Just as an example, if you have `body {background: none}` anywhere in your code, your question code will not be used.

Answer (score 1):

your css is not valid. You should be using background: rather than background-image: if you are using shorthand css.

```
.login-img-body{

    background: url('../img/loginWallpaper.jpg') no-repeat center center fixed; 

    -webkit-background-size: cover;

    -moz-background-size: cover;

    -o-background-size: cover;

    background-size: cover;

}
```